Two triangles with two pairs of collinear sides (is there an elegant solution to find angle $x$?)
I recently saw this problem online:

The solution provided involved quite a lot of trig and the use of calculator. So I'm curious to see if someone can provide a simpler solution using the fact that $\overline{\text{AB}}, \overline{\text{AD}}$ and $\overline{\text{BC}}$ have the same lengťh.
What I've tried so far is to just connect $\overline{\text{AC}}$ and $\overline{\text{BD}}$ (which gives two isosceles triangles) and thought that was all I needed, but I just wasn't able to find the angle $x$ regardless.
So, is there a simple/elegant approach to find the angle $x$?

Is there any intuition behind why you expect there to be a simple/elegant approach?

@Pranay Intuitively I just expected it to have a simpler solution using that there are three identical lines. Ofc that intuition might very well be wrong. Not at all sure if it has one, and looking online it seems that it don't. But thought it might be worth to post it here in hopes for a simpler solution.

There might be a synthetic solution with regular pentagons given the 108 apex.


(1) Draw equilateral triangle $BCE$ as shown.
(2) Draw $\angle BAF=36^{\text o}$ and let $AF$ cuts $EB$ produced at $F$.
(3) Notice that $\angle ABF=72^{\text o}$. This in turn implies that  $\angle AFB=72^{\text o}$ and hence $AB=AF$.
(4) Note also that $\angle DAF=60^{\text o}$. Hence $\Delta AFD$ is an equilateral triangle.
(5) Hence all red lines in the figure are equal.
(6) Because $\Delta ABE$ is isosceles and $\angle ABE=108^{\text o}$, therefore $\angle BAE=\angle BEA=36^{\text o}$.
(7) Note that $\angle EAF=\angle EFA=72^{\text o}$. Hence $AE=FE$.
(8) Thus $\Delta DAE \cong \Delta DFE$ (SSS) and hence $\angle DEF=\angle DEA$.
(9) Together with $\angle BEA=36^{\text o}$, we have $\angle DEB=18^{\text o}$.
(10) Finally note that $\Delta BDC \cong \Delta BDE$ (SAS) implies that $\angle BCD=\angle BED$.
(11) Hence $\angle BCD=18^{\text o}$.

Great answer aswell! Thanks. I'm having easier to understand all the steps in this answer and feel it's more simple, so for that reason I'm gonna give you the checkmark.


we draw a perpendicular on AB at A. Extend BA from A to meet circle j at K. Extend BC to meet the drawn perpendicular at N. Connect N to K, it intersect the circle j at M. clearly triangle AKM if the reflect of triangle ABC about AN so we have:
$\angle ABC=\angle AKM=48^o$
Also:
$\angle AEC=24+48=72^o$
$[\overset{\large \frown}{BD}+\overset{\large \frown}{GH}]\times \frac12=\frac12 (24+\overset{\large \frown}{GH})=72^o$
$\Rightarrow GH=2\times 72-24=120^o\Rightarrow \angle HDG=\angle ADG=60$
That is triangle ADG is equilateral and we have:
$\angle DAG=60^o$
Also:
$\angle BAG\angle MAK=24+60=84^o$
$\Rightarrow\overset{\large \frown}{GM}=120-(84+24)=12^o$
angle BCD is exterior angle of triangle DCG , so we have:
$\angle BCD=\angle BGD+\angle MDG=\frac{\overset{\large \frown}{BD}}2+\frac{\overset{\large \frown}{GM}}2$
$\angle BCD=\frac {12}2+\frac {24}2=18^o$

Great! This is the type of answer I was looking for :) Although I don't understand the "why's" for some of them, like why the angle [BD + GH] × ½ part. But what about the part: angle KBG = BAG = 24 + 60 .. there shouldn't be no KBG there right?

@Prim3numbah, I corrected some errors and added mores data to answer questions in your comment.

$\text{C}$ is where green meets yellow and $\text{D}$ is red/blue.

The vertical difference between $\text{C}$ and $\text{D}$ is $\sin(48^\circ)-\sin(24^\circ)$ and the horizontal difference between $\text{C}$ and $\text{D}$ is $\cos(24^\circ)-(1-\cos(48^\circ))=\cos(24^\circ)+\cos(48^\circ)-1$.
Therefore, the line parallel to $\overline{\text{AB}}$ through $\text{C}$ and the line $\overline{\text{CD}}$ form an angle $\theta$ where
$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{\sin(48^\circ)-\sin(24^\circ)}{\cos(24^\circ)+\cos(48^\circ)-1}$$
so $\theta=30^\circ$ and $x=48^\circ-30^\circ=18^\circ$.

How did you solve that last equation???

@Dominique; with a calculator!

This is a good answer, but I was looking for a solution more in line with the recent post made by Sirous.
